# I don't understand the meaning of ls [aDt]*t?t

Tags: linux, bash, shell, glob

Probably a quick and easy one for you guys but I can't actually find an answer anywhere.

What does this mean? Break it down for me, please?

Comment: The answer is in the bash manual in the "_Pathname Expansion_" section.

Comment: It's a filename [wildcard (aka "glob") pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"[aDt]*.t?t"  is an expression of the "shell expansion" (there are several types, this one is "pattern matching").

This expansions use wildcard-type items to match not only a single name, but multiple.

In the case of ls command (your question, but the same applies to any command), it will list all the files having a matching name, but not other files.

```
[aDt]  matches any of the character "a", "D", "t"
*      matches any number (even zero) of any character
?      matches any single character
```

This expression can match, for example

```
  D-data.txt
  a-what.tNt
  t.tst
```

but not

```
  mega.txt      (first letter is not a, D or t)
  ciao.TXT      (the uppercase T of TXT do not match)
  ciaotxt       (does not contain a dot)
```

This is only a partial reply, things are much more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

The naswer is simple:

- `[aDt]` : the character `a` or `D` or `t`.
- `*` : zero or more (any) characters.
- `.` : the dot.
- `t` : the `t` character.
- `?` : any (single) character.
- `t` : the `t` character.